# Change directory in aix

Tags: linux, aix

I am currently using AIX operating system.

I have directories lined up like below

```
/directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4/directory5
```

and my user directory is at location

```
/u/grv/
```

now i want to go to directory4 from my home

i know this can be achieved by givint the following command

```
cd /directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4
```

but is there any way if i type the following command it will take me to the directory

```
cd directory4
```

I just want to know whether this can be achieved.

Comment: Take a look at the `CDPATH` environment variable in the bash manual.

Comment: @barmar Thanks man. It worked for me. I just set this environment variable and it worked.

Comment: You could create a symlink: `ln -s /long/long/path short; cd short`

Answer (score 1):

When this directory4 is not in the same subdirectory of /u or /u/grv this is not possible.

However: if the dir is in on of those dirs as a subdir. then you can chnage to this dir using:

`cd ../<directory to 4>` or `cd /<direcory to 4>`

 The `..` also can be used multiple times to go to root dir where you can use the full path to go to directory 4.

However then it is easer to start at the root dir with

```
cd /
```

and got to the directory4 as you already showed.

```
`cd /directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4`
```

Comment: He said it can't be done, it's the answer to your question

Comment: it can be done by setting environment variable CDPATH

Comment: and thanks for downvote..now i got a warning for not asking question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I wrote incorrectly that you could try to overrule the cd command (it is an internal command).

What I should do, is make an alias.sh file and source that file (using a dot: `. ${HOME}/bin/alias.sh`) in your .bashrc or .profile. In the alias file make some aliassen for your favorite dir's:

```
alias cd1="cd /directory1"
alias cd2="cd /directory1/directory2"
alias cd3="cd /directory1/directory2/directory3"
alias cd4="cd /directory1/directory2/directory3/directory4"
alias reset="rm /directory1/directory2/directory3/log/*"
```

Comment: `cd` has to be a builtin command, it cannot be a standalone executable

Comment: @Zsigmond: Tx, I knew but didn't think about it.